# Not contains in Reg ex

Tags: java, regex

I am facing issues when using **not contains** in regx

```
 some text good foo and some text and good koo 
 good foo and some text (no indication of koo)
```

I like to filter all good foo records but no **koo**. In this case only 2nd record. I tried to use

`.* good foo.*((?!(good koo)).)* .*`

But it is flagging all the records having the word **good foo**

```
/* no indication of good koo, so expected is true) */
println("good foo and some text (no indication of koo)".matches(".*good foo.*((?!(good koo)).)* .*"))  

/* indication of good koo, so expected is false) */
println("good foo and some text good koo".matches(".*good foo.*((?!(good koo)).)* .*"))
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide some example of expected result along with logic which lead you to that result?

Comment: Also if you have some code and you believe it should work, post it because problem may not be in regex but how you are using it.

Comment: sorry, I just added some samples, hope that will help

Comment: You may use [`string.matches("(?!.*\\bgood koo\\b).*\\bgood foo\\b.*");`](https://regex101.com/r/HbWRwa/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do this match line by line, then the following pattern should work:

```
^(?=.*\bgood foo\b)(?!.*\bgood koo\b).*$
```

### Demo

This uses positive and negative lookaheads to assert that `good foo` *does* appear somewhere in the line, and that `good koo` does *not* appear in that same line.  Then, it accepts anything else to appear in that line.

Note that I put word boundaries `\b` around `good foo` and `good koo` to ensure that, for example, the pattern does not give a false flag match to `good food`.